# Show items starting from specific row in android listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list view with 100 items. On creating the `ListView` shows first 10 items. If the user clicks ShowRemainingItems option from the menu, I want to display items from 11 to 100. I tried with the below code, but it did not work.The list view is not getting lodaed on clicking the menu. Can some one help?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init user list
    ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.dataList);
    this.listAdapter = new DataListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_cell);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.ShowRemainingItems) {
     Toast.makeText(this,"refresh clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listAdapter.clear();
        // Update the 'listData' according to your preferences like displaying the items from 11 to 100
        // Notify the adapter about the change
        updateDataList();
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void updateDataList() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Update data list called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.dataList);
    list.setSelectionFromTop(11,12);
    Toast.makeText(this,"setSelectionFromTop selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And the `Datalistadapter.java`

```
public class DataListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<User> userList;
    private int layoutRessource;

    public ArrayList<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public DataListAdapter(Context ctx, int layoutResourceId) {
        super(ctx, layoutResourceId);
        this.userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        this.layoutRessource = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public void addUser(User usr) {
        this.userList.add(usr);
    }

    public void removeUser(String usrId) {
        for (User usr : userList) {
            if (usr.getId().equals(usrId)) {
                this.userList.remove(usr);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
        if(userList != null)
            userList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return this.userList.size();
        return Math.min(10, this.userList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public User getItem(int position) {
        return this.userList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = li.inflate(this.layoutRessource, null);
        }

        // Get row user
        User currentUser  = getItem(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "SIZE: " + this.userList.get(position));

        // Id
        TextView idLabel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer below. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first clear the update the dataset of the adapter and then then notify the adapter about the change so that it can update the UI accordingly. Also don't fetch the ListView each time you are using it and set the Adapter to it, instead make it as global.

```
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Init user list
    list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.dataList);
    this.listAdapter = new DataListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_cell, listData);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.ShowRemainingItems)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"refresh clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listData.clear();
        // Update the 'listData' according to your preferences like displaying the items from 11 to 100
        updateDataList();
        // Notify the adapter about the change
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    else if(id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Settings clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I have added the updateDataList() and made changes , still I am not able to see the changes in the listview

Comment: This solution will not work as OP has several problems in the adapter as well. Please look at the answer below about the problems stated in the comments inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code. However, I took the responsibility of fixing and here's the modified code. Please note that the code is not tested, so please modify as per your further requirement.

I have added comments where you have done mistakes. Please check them carefully. Thanks.

```
private ArrayList<User> userList;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize the userList here
    userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    userList = getFirst10Items();

    // Initialize ListView and pass the userList into your adapter
    ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.dataList);
    this.listAdapter = new DataListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_cell, userList);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.ShowRemainingItems) {
        // Remove the following. This will not be needed
        // listAdapter.clear();

        updateDataList();
        // Not necessary. As the updateDataList has already the notifyDataSetChanged command
        // listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void updateDataList() {
    // Do not initiate the ListView again. Just use the ListView that is already created.
    // ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.dataList);

    // This is not the way of selecting items in your ListView. I think your knowledge of how adapter works is wanting
    // list.setSelectionFromTop(11,12);

    // Here's the new implementation. 
    ArrayList<User> userListFor11To100 = getTheRemainingUsers();
    userList.addAll(userListFor11To100);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<User> getTheRemainingUsers() {
    // You need to implement the getTheRemainingUsers function yourself which will get the data for the position 11 to 100 in the ListView
    // Just use userList.add(user) function instead of using listAdapter.addUser() function
}

public List<User> getFirst10Items() {
    // You need to implement the getFirst10Items function yourself which will get the data for the position 0 to 10 in the ListView
    // Just use userList.add(user) function instead of using listAdapter.addUser() function
}
```

Now you need to modify your adapter like the following.

```
public class DataListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<User> userList;
    private int layoutRessource;

    // Modify the constructor to get the userList passed from the activity to the adapter.
    public DataListAdapter(Context ctx, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<User> userList) {
        super(ctx, layoutResourceId);
        this.userList = userList;
        this.layoutRessource = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public void addUser(User usr) {
        this.userList.add(usr);
        // Call the notifyDataSetChanged after adding each user to the list
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeUser(String usrId) {
        for (User usr : userList) {
            if (usr.getId().equals(usrId)) {
                this.userList.remove(usr);
                break;
            }
        }
        // Call the notifyDataSetChanged after removing each user to the list
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
        if(userList != null) {
            userList.clear();
            // Call the notifyDataSetChanged after removing all user from the list
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.userList.size();
        // The following statement is wrong!! Return the actual size of the list all the time. 
        // return Math.min(10, this.userList.size()); 
    }

    @Override
    public User getItem(int position) {
        return this.userList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = li.inflate(this.layoutRessource, null);
        }

        // Get row user
        User currentUser  = getItem(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "SIZE: " + this.userList.get(position));

        // Id
        TextView idLabel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);

        // Set something to the TextView. Now its showing nothing. 
        idLabel.setText(currentUser.getId());

        return row;
    }
}
```